# Jquery leer valor de un input como variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Buenas tardes se tiene el siguiente código `HTML` y `JQUERY`, lo que se desea hacer es poner en el `<input type="text" id="txt-nombre">` el nombre de la variable **`"nombre"`** que ya está creado en el `JQUERY` y al darle **"Click"** en el botón debe de salir el siguiente mensaje: **`Hola juan`**.
Como pueden observar en el código `JQUERY` no me devuelve ningún valor, aunque creo que debería.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#btn-enviar",function () {
        var variable = $("#txt-nombre").val();
        var nombre = "Juan";
        var apellido = "Rodriguez";
        alert("Hola "+$("#"+variable).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt-nombre">
<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="btn-enviar">
```

Entonces, ¿es posible hacer esto?, ¿hay alguna forma de llegar al resultado?.
**Como siempre agradeciendo a las respuestas a este problema.**

**NOTA:** Se desea colocar una variable en el `<input type="text" id="txt-nombre">` **(no colocar un valor, en su lugar debe ser una variable)** y en un mensaje debe salir el **"valor"** de tal **"variable"** que se ingreso en la `caja de texto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno amigos la solución al problema se resolvería de la siguiente manera usando la función `eval()`, comparto el siguiente código por si alguien más le sirva el contenido.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#btn-enviar",function () {
        var variable = $("#txt-nombre").val();
        var nombre = "Juan";
        var apellido = "Rodriguez";
        alert("Hola "+ eval(variable));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt-nombre">
<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="btn-enviar">
```

Answer (score 1):

No se realmente que es lo que quieres pero si es que te salga el valor de la caja de texto te valdría con esto.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#btn-enviar",function () {
        var variable = $("#txt-nombre").val();
        var nombre = "Juan";
        alert("Hola "+variable);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt-nombre">
<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="btn-enviar">
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/val/) de JQuery, el método `val` sirve para obtener el valor actual del primer elemento que empate de varios.

Por ejemplo:

Si tienes un input en HTML con un `value="Hola"` así:

```
<input type="text" value="Hola" id="txt-nombre">
```

Para obtener el valor del atributo `value` sería así:

```
let contenidoCaja = $("#txt-nombre").val()
alert(contenidoCaja)
```

Dando en pantalla: **Hola**

Por lo tanto y con eso en mente, deberías modificar la línea del `alert()` de este modo:

```
alert("Hola "+"#"+variable);
```

Donde solo concatenamos los *strings* con la variable que contiene el `value` ingresado en el `input` por que lo que tratas es de asignar el valor del input en el mensaje del `alert`

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <input type="text" id="txt-nombre">
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="btn-enviar">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on("click","#btn-enviar",function () {
                var variable = $("#txt-nombre").val();
                var nombre = "Juan";
                var apellido = "Rodriguez";
                alert("Hola "+"#"+variable);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hola @Aprendiz al ejecutar el código que me pasas solo muestra el valor de `variable`, pero en realidad lo que se quiere es que el valor que se ingresa en el `campo de texto` sea leída como una variable para luego mostrar su valor en un mensaje. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Añado el ejemplo @DanielR.Anccasi pues he probado lo que te respondí y funciona

Answer (score 0):

En la pregunta planteas que:

> ... lo que se desea hacer es poner en el  el nombre de la variable "nombre" que ya está creado
>   en el JQUERY ...

En jQuery, el método para asignar el valor de un `input` es `val()`, como bien explica [la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/val/):

> Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.
>
> ---
>
> Establece el valor de cada elemento en el conjunto de elementos
>   coincidentes.

La sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
elemento.val(valor)
```

Donde `elemento` es el elemento HTML (en este caso el `input`); `valor` es el valor que quieres asignar a ese elemento, en este caso el contenido de la variable `nombre`.

Entonces, si lo que quieres es asignar el valor de `nombre`  al `input` sólo tiene que hacer esto:

```
$("#txt-nombre").val(nombre);
```

La documentación dice que `val()` sirve también para **obtener** el valor actual del elemento. En ese caso, `val()` se usa sin ningún parámetro:

```
var variable = $("#txt-nombre").val();
```

En este caso, `variable` adquirirá el valor actual que haya en el `input`.

Viendo tu código, parece que lo que hay es una confusión entre **asignar** que se hace con `elemento.val(valor)` y **obtener** que se hace con `elemento.val()`.

#### Prueba de asignar

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#btn-enviar",function () {
        var nombre = "Juan";
        $("#txt-nombre").val(nombre);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt-nombre">
<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="btn-enviar">
```

---

#### Prueba de obtener

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#btn-enviar",function () {
        var nombre=$("#txt-nombre").val();
        console.log(nombre);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt-nombre" value="María">
<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="btn-enviar">
```

Answer (score 0):

pues realmente hay muchas formas de hacerlo. Varias de las respuestas de arriba son correctas.

Acá te paso otra.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#btn-enviar",function () {
        var input = $("#txt-nombre");
        var nombre = "Juan";
        alert("Hola " + input.val());
    });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt-nombre">
<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="btn-enviar">
```

Lo que hago es crear una variable "input" y le asigno el objeto, por lo que puedo hacer uso de sus atributos y eventos.